# Model of messages and conversations - chat - production version (The Right Approach)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Can the following model for conversations and chat messages be used in production applications?
If the database grows and there will be more news, is the following approach appropriate? I am asking for advice

**Conversation**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ConversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    members: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Conversation", ConversationSchema);
```

**Message**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    conversationId: {
      type: String,
    },
    sender: {
      type: String,
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Message", MessageSchema);
```

Comment: This is a popular System Design interview question. This design is simple enough to start with, but there are many things that can cause you to tweak this. For example, you might want to consider storing the last sent message in the conversation model, to speed up rendering of the "my conversations" screen. And so on.